# Is it possible to replicate multipage application with webpack without involving backend?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, single-page-application, multi-page-application

I need to split my application into 2 different parts, lets say simple app and main app.
Simple app *is in pure javascript without any dependencies*, and main app is a *react* application. They both should be available under the same domain with different paths, like `${domain}/simple` and `${domain}/main` .
Is this possible to accomplish with `webpack`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes according to their [docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#multi-page-application) this is how you do it

```js
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    pageOne: './src/pageOne/index.js',
    pageTwo: './src/pageTwo/index.js',
    pageThree: './src/pageThree/index.js',
  },
};
```

Just created a repo with a working example, if you want to take a better look how to implement it,
here you go https://github.com/MattiSig/multipage-webpack

Comment: Thanks. I am also using html-webpack-plugin and I didn't realize at first how can I achieve my goal.  Your example helped me to do necessary changes on my side and also update the usage of html-webpack-plugin to split application. Thanks a lot!

Comment: My pleasure, was curious how to get this done myself. Feel free to star the repo if it helped :)